# Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function given by $f(x)=x+\int_0^1(xy+x^2)f(y)\,dy$. Find $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let the definite integral be $a$

Then $f(x)=x+a$

So
$$f(x)=x+\int_0^1(xy+x^2)(y+a)dy$$

$$f(x)=x+\frac x3 +\frac x2 +\frac {x^2}{2} + x^2a$$

After substituting $f(x) = x+a$, a really complex integral is obtained which lead me to believe that this is not the proper method to go about.

How is this solved?

Comment: $a$ is a function of $x$. So inside the integral it is $a(y)$

Comment: We have $f(x) = x[1 + \int_0^1 yf(y) dy] + x^2 \int_0^1 f(y)dy$ so your function is on the form $f(x) = Ax + Bx^2$. This is the function to substitute in and solve for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @MathLover i don’t quite understand how the inside function a(y). If a is function of x, then the inside integral should only have y terms in it

Comment: My point is that $f(x) = x + a(x)$ then inside integral on RHS $f(y) = y+a(y)$. So we cannot treat it as constant when integrating with respect to $dy$.

Comment: @MathLover ok I get it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: denote $I_0 := \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx$, $I_1 := \int_0^1 x\, f(x)\, dx$.
Integrating the given relation on $[0,1]$ one obtains that
$$
(1)\qquad I_0 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} I_1 + \frac{1}{3} I_0.
$$
Multiplying both sides of the relation by $x$ and integrating again:
$$
(2)\qquad I_1 = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} I_1 + \frac{1}{4} I_0.
$$
Now it remains to solve the linear system (1)-(2) in the unknowns $I_0$ and $I_1$.

Comment: What did you integrate in the first step exactly?

Comment: In first step, you just integrate both sides, $ \displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx = \int_0^1 \bigg[x + \int_0^1 (xy+x^2) f(y) \, dy \bigg] \ dx $